# Gitorious - where is the 'View project members' permission being stored?

Tags: gitorious

I have a project that the owner has been resigned. I'm going to add a new member to this project. By changing the `owner_id` and the `user_id`:

```
# script/console
>> project = Project.find_by_slug
>> project.owner_id = 
>> project.user_id =
>> project.save
```

I can see the additional links after pressing Ctrl+F5:

- Add repository
- Edit project
- Manager access

But there is no `View project members` link to `Add new member`. Where is the `View project members` permission being stored in the MySQL? Or how can I grant `Add new member` permission to myself via Gitorious console?

PS: Gitorious version 2.3.1